# Frames per second for Javascript powered animations?

Tags: javascript, performance, frame-rate

I'm working on a site that abuses Javascript pretty heavily for some constant animation effects; namely scrolling backgrounds. When running maximized in Firefox 3.6.13 at 1920x1080 it seems to lag, and sometimes ends up a bit skippy. When running at a smaller size though (resized to 50%-75%) it's very smooth.

I was just wondering if its possible to grab the number of discarded processes, or loosely the FPS, that a given animation is running at. The animation is actually driven by `window.setInterval()` with a delay of 10 (1/100 of a second).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/why-jquery-uses-77-fps-by-default-in-animation

Credit to Google for the link :)

Comment: Thankyou **benhowdle89**; Great information, I will certainly play with the `interval` property to see if there is any gain in animation quality for the jQuery powered animations. However, I'd still like to know if it's possible to grab the number of discarded iterations of `setInterval`, seeing as the animation in question is not in fact powered by jQuery. I'll change my question for relevance.

Comment: can you not do something like in PHP, if (!setInterval)?

Comment: **@benhowdle89**; Care to elaborate on `if(!setInterval)`?

Comment: Well in PHP you can check if something failed or didn't happen (by using ! in front of something), so maybe there is someway of doing the same in JS. So check if the setInterval didn't work and add to a counter each time it failed, which you could then at least see how many times it fails

Comment: Hmm, so perhaps another function registered to `setInterval`, but at a delay of 1 (1 msec), that checks the number of times my animation event has fired? I'll look into that.

Comment: yeah i'd go for that. Thats bloody fast animation by the way ;)

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Having added `eFired++` to the animation handler, and an additional `setInterval` handler that dumps and resets `eFired` every second, I can see quite a difference. ~23 at 1920x1080. ~42 at 960x1080. +70 at very small (unusably small).